# Writing registry key with NSIS fails

Tags: windows, registry, nsis, registrykey

I have a relative simple NSIS-installer, which needs to write some keys to the registry. Unfortunately this does not work. Relevant code-parts are:

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin

Function .onInit
  WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps" "" ""
FunctionEnd
```

As far as I understand it, .oninit is called in every case? Nevertheless after executing this installer's .exe, I do not see my new Key "LocalDump". What could be wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: 64-bit Windows?

Comment: @Anders yes, indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit Windows has [two registry "views"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector) and 32-bit applications see the 32-bit view by default. You can use the `SetRegView` instruction to force a 32-bit NSIS installer to write to the 64-bit view:

```
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
${If} ${RunningX64}
  SetRegView 64
  WriteRegStr ... value for 64-bit systems
  SetRegView LastUsed
${Else}
  WriteRegStr ... value for 32-bit systems
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

`.onInit` is always executed but you should not really make changes to the system there because the user might cancel the installation. You should do most of the installation related operations in `Section`s.